When is 'gcc -c' not enough to compile into a binary but needs 'gcc -o'?
I used to compile C programs with a command line like this:
gcc -c myexecutable mysource.c
After that I could run 'myexecutable' from shell. In the past this always worked for me.
With a tool that I am currently trying to compile, this does not work.
It says:
gcc: error: myexecutable: No such file or directory
When I compile it using
gcc -o myexecutable mysource.c
it works and I can run myexecutable.
When I compile it using
gcc -c mysource.c
it creates the mysource.o object file which is not executable.
I read that the '-c' option does not link and probably in earlier projects I did not have to link.
My questions are:

In which situations is it needed to link?
How can I check the source file for these attributes?
Was it just coincidence that the programs before did not need to be linked , so I did not have this problem earlier, or was it not needed in earlier gcc version (2.95 or so)?
Should I compile with '-o' from now on in general?

I only have one single source file and no dependencies from external files or libraries.
The environment has gcc-9 if that is relevant.

I'm not sure I believe gcc -c myexecutable mysource.c ever worked.  That would treat myexecutable as a linker script, ignore it because -c implies don't link, and then compile mysource.c to produce an object file named mysource.o.

@G.M. Maybe they ran it with -o at one point and so an old executable is sitting in the same directory, not corresponding to the most recent code compiled.

@Lundin Indeed.  Sounds plausible.

Or maybe you actually did gcc -C? Which is some weird "do not discard comments" option.

Agree with previous comments: The premise of the question is wrong. "In the past this always worked for me." shouldn't be correct. -c doesn't produce an executable. -o is also not the solution, since it only specifies the output file name, regardless of whether it is a linked executable or an object file. The important part is that -c must be dropped in the call that actually should produce the executable. Linking is always required, but without -c GCC will compile and link in one if necessary (because a source file rather than an object file is given as input).


In the past this always worked for me.

This can simply not be correct. -c means do not link, in which case you don't get an executable. Period. You will get object files.

In which situations is it needed to link?

Whenever you need an executable (or library etc).

How can I check the source file for these attributes?

I don't understand what you mean. The code? A make file? The source code has nothing to do with this.

Was it just coincidence that the programs before did not need to be linked , so I did not have this problem earlier, or was it not needed in earlier gcc version (2.95 or so)?

You were doing something wrong or remembering wrong. Perhaps you ran gcc once with -o and executed an old executable from there on.

Should I compile with '-o' from now on in general?

Yes, always. Assuming you want an executable.

The environment has gcc-9 if that is relevant.

gcc has worked the same for as long as I can remember.
